# Apache Camel "transacted" does not work well with sql component`s "outputType=StreamList"

Tags: apache-camel

In my transacted camel route I need to:

1. Call oracle *package* to set value for variable in this *package*;
2. Execute sql statement which is using variable from *package*;

Note that package variable is only visible in connection from which it was set - so I need to use "transacted" here.

Here is a sample code which demonstrates the problem:

```
from("direct-vm:process")
    .transacted()
    .to("sql:call my_pack.set_v1('10')")
    .to("sql:select my_pack.get_v1 from dual?outputType=StreamList")
    .split(body()).streaming()
        .log("${body}")
    .end();
```

Result for above code will be: **GET_V1=null**

If I comment ".transacted()" I will get: **GET_V1=10**

If I remove "StreamList" option from sql and un-comment ".transacted()": **GET_V1=10**

**Question**: is it not possible for "transacted" to work with sql component`s "StreamList" option?

**Additional info:**

If I start above route in multiple threads, like this:

```
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("10", "10");
            map.put("20", "20");
            map.put("30", "30");
            map.put("40", "40");
            map.put("50", "50");

            map.forEach((key, values) -> {
                from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")
                        .setHeader("key", constant(key))
                        .setHeader("value", constant(values))
                        .inOnly("seda:processParallel");
            });
            from("seda:processParallel?concurrentConsumers=5")
                    .to("direct:process");

            from("direct:process")
                    //.transacted()
                    .to("sql:call my_pack.pset_v1(:#value)?dataSource=generalDataSource")
                    .to("sql:select :#key key, my_pack.get_v1 value from dual?outputType=StreamList")
                    .split(body()).streaming()
                        .to("log:row")
                    .end();
```

I will get inconsistent results:

```
KEY=**20**, VALUE=**50**
KEY=**50**, VALUE=**40**
KEY=**40**, VALUE=**20**
KEY=**10**, VALUE=**30**
KEY=**30**, VALUE=**10**
```

Transaction manager configures as shown below:

```
    @Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is only for same database , you dont need transacted() which is XA transaction
usually it convers different resources for example one JMS , another Database

Comment: thanks for your reply. I`ve added additional info to the initial question - if I run my route in multiple threads - I get inconsistent results

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you have defined your transactionManager ? In particular, did you bind this txManager to your datasource ?

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="generalDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: added this info to my question info.